# Require a suitable character set for sending SMS messages from a webform

Tags: character-encoding, sms

I've built a webform that allows customers to send SMS messages and I want to restrict the character sets the form will allow so that the encoding leaves the message at 160 chars. If a user types in a Japanese or Cyrillic character, the encoding will switch to 16bit and the length of the SMS will shorted to 70 characters. I don't want to allow this.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS#Message_size

In a HTML form you can specify the char set with

```
form accept-charset="character_set"
```

Where 'character_set' is something like UTF8 or ISO-8859-1. GSM 3.38 defines the SMS message characters (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38)

Is there any way to set this restriction in my webform?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to limit the form to the GSM 3.38 alphabet by using `accept-charset`, it is not among the allowed HTML character sets.

The only way would be to add a javascript listener function on keypress event and check each entered character against allowed ones.